# CK editor CKFinder, Drag en drop image is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have a problem when integrating CKFinder to CKeditor.

I change Base Dir and Base Url in something like

http://localhost:8080/Appli/userfiles/
C:\Files\Appli\WebContent\userfiles

and in JS

```
filebrowserBrowseUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder//core/connector/java/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&currentFolder=/help/',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&currentFolder=/help/',
```

When I Dragged my image on CKEditor, the image appears a few second with (upload with success) but it disappeared after and I have a "undefined" with a little red cross.

Is There something with my baseURL and it didn't find "userfiles " ?

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration

You should not have `java/connector.php` unless you have changed it in `web.xml` where this virtual path is defined:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>
        /ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java
    </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you have default setup, it should be e.g.

```
filebrowserUploadUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder/core/connector/java/connector.java?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&currentFolder=/help/'
```

There is also a mistake in path (double slash) - `filebrowserUploadUrl: './pages/js/libJS/ckfinder//core`

Comment: thanks , there was an error in the name of the connector so it didn't find him.